# List all elements in array containing certain word in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search, strpos

I'm attempting to make a search feature for my website using PHP. Right now, I have this code to create an array of all files in a directory, which works just fine, but I've hit a snag with my next step. I want it to now list all elements in that array that contain a certain word (the users search), this way I can do something with them later in HTML. My idea was to make a loop that runs strpos for each element and list only the ones it finds matches for. I've tried that, but it always gave me nothing. This is my honest attempt:

```
<?php
    $search = "Pitfall";

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.')) as $filename)
    {
        if ($filename->isDir()) continue;

        foreach ($filename as &$result)
        {
            $pos = strpos($result, $search);

            if ($pos === true) {
                echo "$result\n";
            } 
        }
    }
?>
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with your conditional:

`if ($pos === true)`

`strpos()` does not return true. It returns the position of the string or false. See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). You could instead use:

`if ($pos !== false)`

**Edited:**

The RecusiveIteratorIterator does not return a string. It returns an object. Here I am typecasting the object so that it gets the correct filename. From there, you don't need to iterate over again, as this is just a string at this point.

```
$search = "wp-config";

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.')) as $filename)
{
    $filename = (string) $filename;

    if (is_dir($filename)) continue;

    $pos = strpos($filename, $search);

    if ($pos !== false) {
        echo "$filename <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, using `===` as opposed to `==` will check to see if the value AND the type are equal, which is why true does not work here. `if($pos == true)` would evaluate.

Comment: Hmmm, tried that, but still the same result. Nothing echos

Comment: That could be because nothing matches... We can't see your data set, so we can't be sure. If you could provide the data found in `$filename`

Comment: have you tried debugging `$pos`? Try `var_dump($pos);`

Comment: If you echo out each `$result`, are you getting what you expect?

Comment: There's no output for the dump or the result. That could definitely be the problem.

Comment: Also, maybe try removing the `&` in `foreach($filename as &$result)`. Not sure why you would want that to be a reference...

Comment: Yea, ensure `$result` has what you want first. Either way, `$pos === true` won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92452/discussion-between-syllith-and-chris).